# Preventing local .gitignore from being pushed to svn repo with git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using git-svn to use git locally and deploy a client's svn repo. However, after migrating the svn ignore entries to the .gitignore, I have to commit those to git.

But I don't want that file being pushed as a commit to the svn repo everytime I do a `git svn dcommit`

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use git exclude instead. See the last section here:

http://help.github.com/ignore-files/

Answer (score 4):

To exclude .gitignore from being pushed upstream you can include it in the .gitignore file.

Simply, add  the line ".gitignore" in your .gitignore file