# Preventing file in git repository from being checked into TFS by git-tfs

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I'm working on a TFS repository where check-ins of unnecessary files are strongly discouraged.

As it stands, some files, like *.gitignore*, fall into a category of unnecessary ones. Is there any way to prevent git-tfs from checking these files into TFS, while still tracking the changes in git?

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236720/preventing-local-gitignore-from-being-pushed-to-svn-repo-with-git-svn) solution, but it prevents git itself to refer to the files in question. I'm, however, interested in masking the files **from TFS check-ins** only.

Comment: why `.gitignore` shouldn't be checked in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The exact goal of git-tfs is to check in tfs, the exact content of the git commits you've created.

> > why .gitignore shouldn't be checked in?
>
> Company policies.

Ahhhhhh, tfs!!!! The [tool that managers impose on their developpers](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/03/Review-Version-Control-Systems) and after throw a spanner in the works by preventing developers to do their works well...
Which company tell its developer which file should be put inside its source control :(

When I was the only one using git-tfs, I used a [global .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore). Now that all the team use git-tfs, we checked in a .gitignore.

But what is the main goal to track a file if you don't want to check it in? Putting it outside works perfectly. I don't see the added value...

PS: I'm one of the main developer of git-tfs because I never want to use TFSVC anymore in my entire life.... (frustration occurs and less good job too!)

Comment: Well, hoped that the answer will be something else, but at least now I know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this is by placing the `.gitignore` file somewhere outside the git repository folder.
Then tell your repository to use this file instead with

```
git config --local --add core.excludesfile "../.gitignore"
```

(in this case the actual file resides one folder up from the repository)

Comment: Will it be included in the git repository itself in this case? I believe it will not. My intention is to still allow versioning of the file. It suggests I should edit my question...